# Securing a thrift web service using wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I secure a thrift service using Identity server and then authenticate a user using RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub. After authenticating a user i wish to use the given session id for corresponding access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note, only the `EntitlementService` of WSO2IS has been exposed using thrift. All others are exposed with as SOAP services.  `EntitlementService Thrift service` is already secured with username/password.  First you need to authenticate using thrift authenticator and call the `EntitlementService Thrift service`.  You can find sample client code from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pep/thrift/)